# jquery validate multiple radio box groups

Tags: jquery, validation, rules

I have two radio box groups:

Yes input id="g1_y" type="radio" name="g1" value="yes" checked="checked"

No input id="g1_n" type="radio" name="g1" value="no"

Yes input id="g2_y" type="radio" name="g2" value="yes" checked="checked"

No input id="g2_n" type="radio" name="g2" value="no"

How do I add a validate rule for the case when 'no' is selected in both groups?

ie. Could be g1=Yes and g2=no or g1=no and g2=yes or g1=yes and g2=yes, but NOT g1=no and g2=no.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (($('#g1_n').is(':checked') && $('#g2_y').is(':checked')) || ($('#g1_y').is(':checked') && $('#g2_y').is(':checked'))){
.....
}
```

But your code should be refactored.

Or [Jquery validation check for radio button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14998083/jquery-validation-check-for-radio-button)

Answer (score 0):

you only need 1 validation, g1 and g2 should not `No'

```js
function validateInput() {
  if($('#g1_n').is(':checked') && $('#g2_n').is(':checked'))
    console.log('You cannot select No for both');
  else
    console.log('Good choices');
}
$('input[type=radio]').on('click', function() {
  validateInput();
})
validateInput();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Yes <input typ="radio" input id="g1_y" type="radio" name="g1" value="yes" checked="checked">
No <input typ="radio" input id="g1_n" type="radio" name="g1" value="no">
<br>
  
Yes <input typ="radio" input id="g2_y" type="radio" name="g2" value="yes" checked="checked">
No <input typ="radio" input id="g2_n" type="radio" name="g2" value="no" >
```

Comment: Hi, I am trying to use jquery.validate rule, I have tried using  require_from_group (by adding a class to the two yes buttons) but this does not seem to work.